# How to use anonymous function php

Tags: php

I have an error with phpstorm when I want to change this function

```
$callback = create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[1]);');
```

by

```
callback = function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[1]);');
```

How to resolve that if it's an error.

Thank you.

Comment: Define the error. That makes it easier to help you.

Comment: `function()` needs to have a body and any argument definitions need to be variables, not strings. The code above is simply invalid PHP. Are you trying to make an anonymous function? If yes, then [here's the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) about those.

Comment: What version of PHP is your interpreter set to within PHPStorm?

Comment: Check the syntax for example #2 on the [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) page. You need to tweak the format somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You shouldn't use `create_function()`. `create_function()` uses `eval()`. `eval()` is evil.**

On a more serious note, `eval()` (and thus `create_function()`) has big security issues. If you're on PHP 5.3 or higher, you should use native anonymous functions instead, in this case:

```
$callback = function($matches) {
    return strtoupper($matches[1]);
}
```

For reference: [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Note that [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2.

Comment: Just for clarify: unlike `create_function`, the `eval` is not always evil, but you should have very good reasons for using it ([relevant discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311507/why-are-eval-like-features-considered-evil-in-contrast-to-other-possibly-harmfu/311510)).

Comment: @Timurib I agree that `eval()` isn't always evil, you should just be VERY careful using it whenever user input is involved while using it, or if the user has any chance of manipulating input passend to `eval()`. If you have the opportunity to use anything else but `eval()`, use something else. Otherwise, sanitize your inputs :D